# Count Distinct values in one column based on other column

Tags: sql

[image]I am trying to count distinct values on Z_l based on value by using with clause. Sample data exercise included below.
[please look at the picture, the distinct values of Z_l based on X='ny'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtnZQ.jpg)

```
with distincz_l as (select ny.X, ny.z_l o.cnt From HOPL ny join (select X, count(*) as cnt from HOPL group by X) o on (ny.X = o.Z_l)) select * from HOPL;
```

Comment: with statement is CTE or cub. change last select to `select * from distincz_l `

Comment: This problem has been solved. I have another issue, I want to compute the distinct value of z_r based on the relation to z_l. please look at the updated picture. the desired output would be a table with 6 rows

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a `WITH` clause, since you just need one single sentence:

```
SELECT z_l, count(1)
FROM hopl
WHERE x='ny'
GROUP BY z_l
;
```

Comment: Thanks, and I want to compute the distinct value of z_r based on the relation to z_l.
please look the updated picture. the desire output would be a table with 6 rows.

Comment: Better explain what represents each table and formulate in natural language what do you expect from your query: "Table X contains cities and tabla Y contains population, and I want to know how many cities there are such that etc etc".

Comment: Thank you for your help!
What I want to do is to create a table that contains the cities from NY to anywhere. So, in HOPL, I should only compute the z_l that the origin is NY, obviously in HOPR, I should compute the destinations(Y) that have the Z_l as their origin. So, here I will have a table that has 6 rows, I mean there are 6 different flights whose origin is NY to anywhere. 
The first output should be "6" and the second output should create a partition based on common Y. If you look at the picture, seattles have orange and chicagos have yellow color.

Comment: For the first question, I created this code:  SELECT z_r, count(1)
FROM hopr, hopl
WHERE hopl.z_l=hopr.z_r
GROUP BY z_r
;

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't still clear to me. Better reformulate your question or write up another one, making sure to include your table's definitions in DDL. (And please do not use custom identifiers like "HOPL" or "z_l" withouh explaining what they mean.)